# Does a babel-node hashbang work?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'd like to make a globally installable NPM package that uses ES6. For this, I thought I'd setup my `bin/scriptname` with the `#!/usr/bin/env babel-node` (which would require the end user to install `babel` as well). Does this work, or is there any other, if possible, more efficient way to do it?

Comment: *Does this work?* I don't know, does it? (Actually yes, it does.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look how other compiled projects like `coffee-script` do it. Usually you'd have an executable bin file that does nothing but require a compiled lib file.

Something like this:

```
project/
  bin/
    project
  lib/
    project.js
  src/
    project.babel
```

And your `/bin/project` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/project.js')
```

As long as `/src/project.babel` is compiled to `/lib/project.js` and they both stay in sync, it should work.

Two ways to do that are to watch and recompile with a build system [like webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or write an [npm prepublish script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to only compile when publishing the package.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a `.babel` extension, since it's all still JS.